# Generating grid lines with CSS gradients

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to generate a grid with alternating solid and dotted lines over a very tall column. The catch is that the solid lines will need to programmatically get farther apart, and in doing so, they should reveal more dotted lines. Here is the code I have so far:

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/etzVJ/

CSS:

```
.test {
    width: 100%;
    height: 2000px;
    background: 
        linear-gradient(white 24px, transparent 24px) 0px -24px,
        linear-gradient(black 24px, transparent 24px),
        linear-gradient(90deg, white 1px, red 1px, red 2px, white 2px);
    background-size: 1px 25px, 1px 50px, 3px 1px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="test">
    &nbsp;
</div>
```

I think I'm pretty close. You can adjust the second background-size(1px 50px) to 1px 75px to push the black lines apart and show two dotted lines. There are two things with this code that aren't quite right, though. First, the line height is actually 31px, which is surprising because I would think that I specified 25px tall gradients. I'm sure I could make these numbers smaller to get the lines to be exactly 25px apart, but I'd like to know why it's taller than expected. Second, sometimes increments of 25px seem to work until you scroll really far down, and then it breaks. Here are the heights required to achieve the desired effect:

Number of dotted lines between solid lines -> Corresponding Background Size

0 -> 1px 25px

1 -> 1px 50px

2 -> 1px 75px

3 -> 1px 99px

4 -> 1px 124px

5 -> 1px 149px

6 -> 1px 174px

7 -> 1px 199px

Why does the code break at 100px, and I have to drop it to 99px? I could certainly code this in, but again, I'd really just like to know what's going on. Thanks!

Comment: Your jsFiddle is producing a blank result

Comment: I don't get a blank result, but it practically crashes my browser.

Comment: I think you can do this a lot more efficiently using background images (data-images, possibly)

Comment: btw, how exactly do you see it breaking at 100px?  I don't see a problem.

Comment: The only browser I have to support is Chrome, and it doesn't slow it down at all. At 1px 100px, there are eight dotted lines between the two solid lines. Do you not see the same thing?

Comment: I see the correct line height, 25. I don't see the line height of 31 px

Answer (score 0):

Doh!! Sorry guys!! This code actually works as intended. My zoom level was inadvertently set to 110% on that tab and that tab only, so I didn't notice. (>.<) That was making it taller than 25px and not work at 100px. I'm embarrassed that's all it was, and apologize for wasting your time. Hopefully you learned something about stacking linear gradients. Thanks again for the responses.